# Could Sue create force fields from the start?

Tags: marvel, fantastic-four

I've wondered if Sue Richards had the ability to create force fields when the four originally mutated, or if the writers added it later (possibly because they thought invisibility wasn't enough against the threats the Fantastic Four frequently came up against). Does anyone know for sure?

Comment: Wikipedia knows for sure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invisible_Woman

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer you're looking for is "no": Sue didn't demonstrate the ability to generate force fields for the first few years of the *Fantastic Four*'s run, though it did appear quite early.

However, the question of whether she was *able* to is a little more interesting, and the answer is:

### Unclear

She first creates a force field in *Fantastic Four* #22, published in 1964. Initially trying to determine the strength of her powers, Reed suggests that she isn't using her fullest potential:

[image]

> **Reed:** Just as I thought! You have greater powers of invisibility than you suspect, Sue! The problem is...how do you learn to control those powers??

She creates her first force field shortly after this, to the astonishment of everyone:

[image]

> **Reed:** Sue! You've done it! You created a shield of invisible energy!

Initially, you'd think this would fall under "greater powers *[...]* than you suspect." Reed, however, being the massive egoist that he is, immediately suggests that her power has been increased as a result of his measuring device:

[image]

> **Reed:** The radiation from my nuclear measuring device must have increased your power, Sue!

Whether Sue was theoretically capable of generating force fields before this event, or whether she was indeed strengthened by Reed's machine, isn't elaborated upon.

Comment: Beat me by *that* much (to paraphrase Maxwell Smart)....

Comment: @RDFozz Your answer was also slightly wrong; Sue first demonstrated the ability to turn objects other than herself invisible in #22 (or, she demonstrates the ability and everybody is *super* surprised by it; this being Silver Age comics, I can't discount the possibility that she demonstrated the power before and the writers just forgot)

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting Sue's comment between the test and her first force field, that she "didn't feel any different, just a little tired." Certainly the first thing I say after someone's done some sort of testing on me, after all. One suspects Stan wasn't fully decided on whether Reed was trying to increase her powers or not.

Comment: You're absolutely right - for some reason, I conflated two stories, and thought she'd turned a hidden door visible in their first encounter w/ Doctor Doom. Just checked, and that must have been in a later story - no sign of it in ht eearly Dr. Doom stories, before issue 22.